# Strip wrapping spaces in a regexp

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wanna find the *Target* string without the wrapping spaces, it can have any non `\s\w\d` characters like `+!#` etc and have arbitrary number of white spaces inbetween, and at the edges(left, right)

```
Target (foo) {bar} [spam] | (foo2)
```

Current expression looks like this:

```
re.search(r"([^\[\]}{()|]+)", "  +34s kj-3 R B# (foo) {bar} [spam] | (foo2)")
```

and group(0) returns:

```
'  +34s kj-3 R B# '
```

the problem with this expr is that I have to write two `if match:` conditions, because it also accepts only spaces as well. So I have to strip it and check again.

Closest solution is to use `\b` like that `r"\b([^\[\]}{()|]+)\b"`, but it "strippes" characters like `+#`:

```
'34s kj-3 R B'
```

**EDIT:** Target string can have no wrapping spaces as well on ether sides.

**EDIT:** Included the rest of the sting in the example `(foo) {bar} [spam] | (foo2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using this one liner :

**Update**

```
print(re.search(r"^[^\(\)\{\}\[\]\|]+"," +34s kj-3 R B#  (foo) {bar} [spam] | (foo2)").group().strip(' \t\n\r'))
```

[Run Here](https://ideone.com/OMmqT2)

Explanation:

- `^[^\(\)\{\}\[\]\|]+` find anything until any kind of bracket from the
  beginning
- `strip(' \t\n\r')` will trim any leading/trailing
  whitespace/tab/newline from this match string.

Comment: I don't think this handles if the string contains a tab space in-between characters.

Comment: It's my fault I guess, but your expressions don't filter out the undesired strings in square brackets, parentheses etc. I think I should refactor my question, to include them as well. sorry for this.

Comment: @lava-lava to be frank you didn't put up a complete input string in the first place thus I went for the substring, now I happen to prepare another string which I guess is what your input string looks like... look at the update at the bottom and let me know is that what you want as the output... you can check the source link if that works ok for you with the output

Comment: The reason I wasn't chaining strip method was that there can be no Target string at all, and you can't group `NoneType` object. But now I realised that I should replace greedy `+` with greedy `*`  r"^[^\(\)\{\}\[\]\|]*". Now everything should work. Thank you.